# Show that there is at least one $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$, such that $ f(x)=-1+x^2+\frac{x^2(x-1)}{3!}f'''(\varepsilon),\quad x\in(0,1). $

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $f(x)$ is three-times differentiable on $[0,1]$, and $f(0)=-1,\;f(1)=0,\;f'(0)=0$. Show that for any $x\in(0,1)$ there is at least one $\varepsilon\in(0,\,1)$, such that
>   $$
> f(x)=-1+x^2+\frac{x^2(x-1)}{3!}f'''(\varepsilon).
> $$

The Taylor expansion of $f$ at $0$ is 
$$
f(x)=-1+\frac{1}{2}f''(0)x^2+\frac{x^3}{3!}f'''(\varepsilon_1),
$$
and at $1$ is
$$
f(x)=f'(1)(x-1)+\frac{1}{2}f''(1)(x-1)^2+\frac{(x-1)^3}{3!}f'''(\varepsilon_2).
$$

But I don't know what I can get.

Comment: To be clear, you're trying to find at least one $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$ and at least one $x \in (0, 1)$ such that the given equation is true? Surely this couldn't necessarily be true for all $x \in (0, 1)$.

Comment: @SimonFraser This necessarily being true for all $x \in (0, 1)$ would imply that thrice-differentiable functions satisfying the given initial conditions must be **exactly equal** to a polynomial over the interval $(0, 1)$. This is simply not true!

Answer (score 6):

The map $f_1(x)= f(x) -(-1+x^2)$ is satisfying $f_1(0)=f_1(1)=f_1^\prime(0)=0$.

Take $x \in (0,1)$ and consider the function

$$g(t) = f_1(t) -A t^2(t-1)$$ where $A$ is chosen such that $g(x)=0$, i.e. $A =\frac{f_1(x)}{x^2(x-1)}$.

As $g(0)=g(1)=g(x)=0$, according to [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) it exists $\alpha_1 \in (0,x)$ and $\alpha_2 \in (x,1)$ such that $g^\prime(\alpha_1) = g^\prime(\alpha_2) =0$. We also have $g^\prime(0)=0$. Therefore one can find $\beta_1 \in (0,\alpha_1)$ and $\beta_2 \in (\alpha_1, \alpha_2)$ with $g^{\prime\prime}(\beta_1)=g^{\prime\prime}(\beta_2) = 0$.

According to Rolle's theorem again, it exists $\epsilon \in (\beta_1,\beta_2) \subseteq (0,1)$ such that $g^{\prime\prime\prime}(\epsilon) = 0$, i.e. $g^{\prime\prime\prime}(\epsilon) = f_1^{\prime\prime\prime}(\epsilon)-3!A =f^{\prime\prime\prime}(\epsilon)-3!A= 0$.

Finally $A =\frac{f_1(x)}{x^2(x-1)} = \frac{f^{\prime\prime\prime}(\epsilon)}{3!}$ leading to the expected result

$$f(x)=-1+x^2+\frac{x^2(x-1)}{3!}f'''(\varepsilon)$$

Comment: (+1) Nice proof!